# min/max functions with date return result with VARCHAR datatype instead of TIMESTAMP

Tags: mysql

I faced the issue related to min/max functions with a date. 
For example - I get Varchar result datatype when querying min(Timestamp(dateColumn)), but I need Timestamp result datatype, I checked these functions with many different functions inside and it returns Varchar always, in every case except when I just call min(dateColumn). In the application I can't cast this operation every time, how could I cope with it?

I have tried to get a date from jdbc ResultSet but I can't track when I have to use result.getTimesatamp. It is impossible to track it.

I expect the min(timestamp('2019-01-01')) or max(timestamp('2019-01-01')) result with Timestamp/Date datatype, but actual result is Varchar result datatype.

Example - SELECT MIN(TIMESTAMP(`orders`.`OrderDate`)) FROM `orders`
The result will be with varchar datatype, but I need the timestamp.
Querying in workbench, dbeaver - results are the same

Comment: Please include the query, or a simplified version of it.

Comment: Also, the function `Timestamp()` without parameters does not exist in MySQL.

Comment: Maybe making a temporary table with the correct table datatypes as workaround and query the temporary table to get the datatype correct in jdbc

Comment: What's the datatype of your date field?

Comment: select MIN(TIMESTAMP(<dateColumn>)) from <table> 
if you run such query in MySQL workbench or dbeaver, I tested it in both applications, you will get varchar datatype result.
Field datatype - timestamp

Comment: A `timestamp` means that the database storage engine saves an integer, but displays text. What exactly are you expecting back? What is "timestamp" data type in your world? It can't be anything but **text** when returned back and you are supposed to parse that text into internal data structures of your language. Are you looking for `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`?

Comment: I suggest making a sqlfiddle to proof this or to show what you mean topicstarter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug in MySQL. You can do:

```
select max(x)
from (
  select timestamp(now()) as x
) as x;
```

Or just use:

```
select min(dateColumn)
```

as use of the `timestamp()`-function is unnecessary in the query.

Comment: Can you provide any sources that confirms it's a bug?

Comment: According to documentation the TIMESTAMP-function returns the date or datetime (as it does). Getting max() out of that should not change the datatype. Unfortunately it does change it to varchar as stated. So it's a bug. Did not check if the bug has been reported, but did verify it in MySQL 5.7.17 and in 8.0.11.

Comment: As ANSI SQL 92 didnt define comparison predicates for a timestamp datatype mine best geuss is that MySQL converts the timestamp to a datetime which does has  comparison predicates before running the max and or min functions

Comment: There is no timestamp-datatype in the query. The timestamp()-function returns a date or a datetime.

Comment: When i run your query i see a clear valid datetime format also after running the max

Comment: How do you determine it *changes* the data type? What does **changes** even mean? How do you see that something is varchar and not timestamp when MySQL shows the result? I don't understand how can `2019-05-08 00:00:01` be considered "varchar", "char" or "timestamp". It's textual representation of an integer, it's transmitted via textual protocol as text, how do you extract the type? Is this timestamp that you refer to missing hours, minutes, seconds? What particular info in the query gives away that it's not *timestamp* but *varchar*. I find this statement ridiculous but I'm missing something

Comment: A varchar is a method of saving variable-length strings, it saves the string in the page file followed by a byte denoting the length. How is it possible that MySQL returns a variable-length string with a byte denoting the length? WHERE? How do you get that info out of the result? It makes no sense.

Comment: Each column for a query (like column in a table) has a datatype. You can check the datatype using an API (like mysqli_fetch_fields-call in mysqli). if you run the query and check the datatype of the result set column, it's a varchar.

Comment: @Mjh i wished MySQL had a get_datatype function to show you the internal datatype more or less the same one where you can find out the collate of a string..

Comment: A `varchar` is **not** a type in PHP or any other language. It's storage type in MySQL. Whether you use `TIMESTAMP(column)` or `MAX(TIMESTAMP(column))` you get a piece of text formatted as `Y-m-d H:i:s`. You don't get an integer, you don't get a float or a magic fairy - you get a piece of text that's formatted the way I explained. What the heck are you talking about? You get the same thing all the time, there's no bug in MySQL and there's no data type on output in any program that you might be using. OP didn't even explain properly what's he referring to, we have no idea at all.

Comment: As said, each column for a query (like column in a table) has a datatype. You can get the datatype of the result set columns using an API. For example, PHP's mysqli extension has a function mysqli_fetch_fields (see the documentation) which returns an array for each column. One of the fields in the array is 'type' which, as the documentation states, is "The data type used for this field". You can use this to determine if your application should treat based on the datatype (like our's does). If you call the mysqli_fetch_fields with the query in question, you will see that the type is a varchar.

Comment: In short, in addition to the query data, there is metadata available for the query result (using an API). One piece of information available in the metadata is the datatype for the result set columns. While the query result of a date and varchar fields may *look* like the same, they can be different datatype.

Comment: OP uses Java. You're referring to PHP. Are you perhaps talking about this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/com-query-response.html#column-type

That's the only thing that would make sense, but your answer doesn't contain anything that would point that you queried and compared results, receiving different hex values for column types. Is that it?

Comment: It does not matter if you access the metadata using PHP or Java. It's the same metadata. And yes, I did check the column type returned (using mysqli_fetch_fields ) and the returned datatype for the column is 0xfd => Protocol::MYSQL_TYPE_VAR_STRING.

Comment: I have table orders with field OrderDate, the datatype is DateTime 
select min(`orders`.`orderdate`) FROM `orders` AS `orders` - return date with Datetime datatype 
select min(TIMESTAMP(MAKEDATE(year(`orders`.`orderdate`),1))) FROM `orders` AS `orders` - resturn string datatype. 
select TIMESTAMP(MAKEDATE(year(`orders`.`orderdate`),1)) FROM `orders` AS `orders` - resturn datetime datatype.
is this behavior right? I can't understand, why max/min returns string datatype. Cause if I querying "SELECT max(year(`orders`.`orderdate`)) FROM `orders` AS `orders`" I'll receive numeric datatype.

Comment: DDL: CREATE TABLE `orders` ( `OrderID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `CustomerID` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL, `EmployeeID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `OrderDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL, `RequiredDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL, `ShippedDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL, `ShipVia` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `Freight` float DEFAULT NULL, `ShipName` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL, `ShipAddress` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL, `ShipCity` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL, `ShipRegion` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL, `ShipPostalCode` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL, `ShipCountry` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, `Invoiced` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL)

Comment: min(datecolumn) will return a date, min(datetimecolumn) will return a datetime. The bug seems to affect functions returning date/datetime when used with an aggregate function. For example min(now()) returns a varchar. Use the query format in the answer to get around the bug and report the bug to MySQL developers.